# Debugger For Visual Studio is not Working

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, iis-7

I am facing a very serious issue with visual studio debugger. My asp.net application is hosted on local IIS server. Yesterday i was debugging my code suddenly it stopped working. I verified w3wp process. It was same as IIS process. Then i tried to download symbols but i am not sure either they are all that i need. I tried attaching debugger on visual studio 10 and visual studio 12. Neither of them is working in this case. I tried to attach debugger of JavaScript but it is also not working.
 Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you building full debugging symbols? If not then the debugger has no information to relate the source code to the in memory activity under the debugger. This is set in the project properties per configuration.

Also ensure the symbols are in the bin folder.

You can validate that VS is loading the right symbols with the Debug | Modules window.

Answer (score 0):

I cleared temporary cache of .NET Framework. then i again deployed my application on IIS with different name and magically everything started working.